# Is it possible to call a method in the same line you create an instance in java

Tags: java, methods, constructor, dot-operator

```
class BooleanWrap{
    boolean b = new Boolean("true").booleanValue(); 
}
```

When I try to do the same with the code below, it doesn't work:

```
class TestCode  {
    public static void main(String[] ar)  {
        TestCode tc = new TestCode().go();
    }

    void go() {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Compile error:

> TestBox.java:6: error: incompatible types
>                   TestBox t = new TestBox().go();

When I change the return type of method `go()` from `void` to class type, then I do not get the error anymore.

```
class TestCode2 {
    public static void main(String[] ar) {
        TestCode2 tc2 = new TestCode2().go();
    }

    TestCode2 go() {
        //some code
    }
}
```

What happens to the object I just created in above code (referenced by `tc2`)? Will it get abandoned?

Answer (score 3):

`TestCode tc = new TestCode().go()` would only work if the `go()` method returns a `TestCode`, since you are assigning it to a variable of `TestCode` type.

In the case of `TestCode2 tc2 = new TestCode2().go();`, if the `go()` method returns a reference to a different instance of `TestCode2` (i.e. not the one for which you called `go()`), the original instance won't be referenced anywhere and would be eligible for garbage collection. In other words, `tc2` would refer to the instance returned by `go()`, which doesn't have to be the same instance as the one created in the main method with `new TestCode2()`.

Comment: yeah, and what about the object? since the only reference variable it was referenced by, now refers some other object.

Comment: @user1851607 the variable tc2 never referred to the instance created by `new TestCode2()`. It referred only to the instance returned by `go()`.

Answer (score 3):

This should work just fine:

```
class TestCode{
    public static void main(String[] ar){
        new TestCode().go();
    }

    void go() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
 }
```

Edit: Additional info

This way you can't save the created instance. It will get destroyed right away in the next garbage collection. So normally, to avoid this unneccessary creation and destruction a static method would be used if the instance itself is not needed.

```
class TestCode{
    public static void main(String[] ar){
        TestCode.go();
    }

    static void go() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
 }
```

Comment: No it wouldn't. You can't chain a void method to a constructor call.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I got confused with the answer below. You are not trying to return anything. I didn't see that.

Comment: Nowhere does this explain what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

As Eran said, the method go() returns nothing, and you're trying to assing that nothing to a variable, your method needs to return something, a TestCode object in this case